# Weird line on top of sprite with transparent background

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

So I am trying to add a sprite to my program. It has a weird bug:

[image]

As you can see on the top of the image there is a black line. Well, that line should not be there. Also, since I don't get any errors I have no idea where the problem might be.

Here is where I set the blend functions:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
// same result: glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version core 330
in vec2 texCoords;
out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D image;

void main()
{
    frag_color = texture(image, texCoords);
}
```

The image was created in [piskel](http://www.piskelapp.com)

- Could that be a problem in the image itself? I highly doubt it, since I verified that on `piskel` and also on GIMP, and both reported that it had an alpha channel.
- I am also only drawing this object plus the background screen with `glClear`, which is a rectangle with a texture mapping. Normal textures are working.

Comment: What values are you setting for the `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`/`_T` texture parameters?

Comment: I am passing GL_REPEAT to both of them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Reto Koradi I discovered the problem. I was previously using this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Now I switched the values to this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
```

And it works fine.

Comment: I would use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. With `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER`, you could still get artifacts.